# Where do the integral signs come from when you solve differential equations and have a "dx" (or similar) on its own?

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

Ok so I can solve (some!) differential equations, but I dont quite understanding what's happening.  For example:

$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{2}{3}v^{-2}
$$

We can rearrange to get all the $v$'s on the left and the $t$'s on the right so we can solve it:

$$
\int 3v^2 dv = \int 2 dt
$$

My question is:  Where did those integral signs come from?!  At first I thought ah well I guess if you have something multiplied by $dt$ (or similar), then that refers to an integral - but in integration by substitution we find $dx$ in terms of $du$ without having to stick an integral sign on the front!  So, what's going on here.  How do we know it's an integral.
Thank you!

Comment: If we have two functions in $dx$ form which are equal, then their integrals must be equal. Here we are using this fact to find $v$ in terms of $t$.(we are trying to eliminate $dv$ and $dt$)

Comment: v is a function whose derivative is dv/dt. Integral is anti derivative and by taking the antiderivative you will get the function back again

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you actually have, doing the same thing on both sides, is
$$
\int_{t_0}^t3v^2\frac{dv}{dt}\,dt=\int_{t_0}^t2\,dt
$$
Now you apply the substitution rule of integration, which is the counter-piece to the chain rule of differentiation, to get
$$
\int_{v(t_0)}^{v(t)}3v^2\,dv=\int_{t_0}^t2\,dt
$$
which you now can solve using the fundamental theorem of calculus, as the anti-derivatives of both integrands are known.

Answer (score 2):

I often think it's more clear to phrase these calculations slightly differently. Multiply both sides by $3 v(t)^2$ to obtain
$$
\tag{1} 3 v(t)^2 v'(t) = 2.
$$
Now we can take antiderivatives of both sides to obtain
$$
v(t)^3 = 2t + C.
$$
This is probably the conclusion that your book wanted to arrive at.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this; when you integrate both sides by $dt$ of the equation, the $dt$ cancels out on the $LHS$ to just leave $dv$. This might be where your confusion comes from.